# How to write Euclid's Algorithm using a stack method in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, stack, computer-science

looking for help here!

Does anyone know how to convert the recursive version of Euclid's algorithm (to find the greatest common divisor GCD) into a version that uses STACK?

Here is the recursive version of Euclid's algorithm:

```
def euclid_gcd(a, b):
    if a == 0:
        return b
    return gcd(b%a, a)
```

Right now I have a starting code to convert to a STACK version of Euclid's algorithm:

```
def euclid_gcd_stack(a, b):
    s = Stack()
    s.push(a)
    s.push(b)

    while s.count() > 0:
        b = s.pop()
        a = s.pop()

 <code to be continued here>
```

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: There isn't really a good answer.  The stack is for remembering what to do after the recursive call.  This function is just tail-recursive, i.e., it doesn't do anything after the recursive call, so there is nothing to remember.   The stack has no purpose.

Comment: Adding one more thing, in Python it is generally better to use the built-in data types when possible.  A list with `append(...)` and `pop()` works just like a stack, and is going to be faster than a custom object type.  If you want a queue instead, just `pop(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def euclid_gcd_stack(a, b):
    s = Stack()
    s.push(a)
    s.push(b)

    while s.count() > 0:
        b = s.pop()
        a = s.pop()

        if a > b:
            a, b = b, a
        if a == 0:
            return b
        else:
            s.push(a)
            s.push(b - a)
``
```